# Find out the maximum amount of individual products so that the profit from the sale is maximum

Tags: logic

I have the following table:

```
                 product 1 |  product 2 | product 3 | product 4 |  limit

raw material 1 |    6      |     4      |    3      |    1      |  1465
raw material 2 |    2      |     3      |    2      |    1      |  1926
raw material 3 |    5      |     4      |    1      |    4      |  1301
raw material 4 |    6      |     3      |    4      |    2      |  1725
raw material 5 |    2      |     3      |    5      |    6      |  1769
raw material 6 |    1      |     1      |    4      |    6      |  1298
profit          |    9      |     7      |    5      |    6
```

We need six raw materials to create four products. Raw materials are given in rows, and products are given in columns in the aforementioned table.

The maximum available amount of raw materials is in `limit` column.

The profit from selling products is in `profit` row.

**I need to find out the maximum amount of individual products so that the profit from the sale is maximum.**

I don't have any idea to do this homework with logical way.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is homework, I wont go in too much detail, however this is typical example of problem solved by [Linear programing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), that is to minimize/maximize linear objective function to given constraints. So you have to maximize your profit, your objective function, while not exceding your material limitations, that are your constraints.